# How to report getting an offer to put malware in my code

Tags: malware

I received an email with the following offer.

> Alina Schatalina  wrote: Would you consider adding our script inside your extension and get monthly payments for it? Our script will inject hidden and safe ads inside browser. These ads can't be noticed by user or Chrome Store. For current number of user we will pay you 300 USD each month, and you can still keep extension...

I can't find Google's email address for reporting this to Google.  Technically, it's not phishing, or Spam. And if I did that, presumably it would just load into the filters.  I think Google might like to investigate this person a bit more.

Comment: after clicking around the Chrome Web store pages, it seems like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-app would be the place to go

Comment: I'm guessing from this page: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/best_practices

Comment: By `I can't find the email to report it to Google` do you mean you don't know `google's email address` to report it, or you can't find the email from `Alina Schatalina `.

Comment: @KareemElashmawy I can't find the Google's email address for reporting this to Google.  (Have edited to make more clear.)

Comment: If you click on "send us feedback" [here](https://developers.google.com/terms/site-policies#contact), a contact form opens. This seems to be the best place as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a developer of extensions, under your developer console, you should be able to create a ticket in which an internal team might be able to further assist you or escalate this issue. I spoke with one of my coworkers about your question and that was his suggestion. Props goes to Brently for this suggestion. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, buried in the fine print at the top of the developer desktop page gives the email address "cws-developer-support@google.com"

Answer (score -1):

I searched a bit, you can try this:

https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/m2/new

Comment: except that none of the options apply to the OP's situation

Comment: If I follow the "I want to report a scam, malware or other problems not listed above", then "I want to report something else" I'm get the options of either a Security Tips page or the Google Help Center.